# Why : Any function from $T\times E$ into $(- \infty, + \infty]$ is be called **integrand**?

Tags: measure-theory

I read an article and I did not understand the definition of the functions "**integrand**" :
[image]

Why : Any function from  $T\times E$ into $(- \infty, + \infty]$ is be called **integrand** ?

An idea please.

Comment: Presumably, because such a function can be *integrated*.

Comment: Or at least, it's something one might want to integrate.

Comment: There's also a grammar error: it should say "is called an *integrand*" or something like that.